Boltzmann distributions on atomic orbitals: infinite degeneracy?
The (unnormalized) Boltzmann probability distribution of states as a function of energy and temperature is given by
$$P(\epsilon_i) \propto  g_i\exp\left(\frac{-\epsilon_i}{k_BT}\right)$$
with $P(\epsilon_i)$ the probability of encountering a state with energy $\epsilon_i$, $k_B$ Boltzmann's constant, $T$ the temperature of the system and $g_i$ the degeneracy of the state in question. In most systems, this seems fine to me. However, when we apply this distribution to atomic orbitals, I get confused.
Specifically, lower energy states correspond to the 'exponential factor' being larger, but they have a lower degeneracy than states of higher energy. This, on its own, should not matter too much: the exponential decrease of that second factor is far 'stronger' than the quadratic increase of the degeneracy in atomic systems. However, this exponential factor never truly goes to zero for these systems: electrons are bound by a finite energy difference, so the energy is never infinite and hence the exponential term is never zero. This seems to me problematic, as in the limit of ionization (or even just really high principal quantum numbers), the degeneracy of states definitely does blow up.
What gives? Obviously, my reasoning is faulty, as it predicts all atoms to be ionized at all times, but that's not what we observe. I've been told that this is all due to interference from other (nearby) atoms, bringing about a 'cut-off' principal quantum number, beyond which the provided reasoning fails due to this interference being too strong. This explanation is dissatisfactory to me. Would we expect full ionisation, then, at low atom number densities, because the distance between atoms is larger? I am troubled by this notion. Can someone clarify this matter to me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Something ignored by the answers here: the exponential factor will simply dominate the degeneracy factor, even as the degeneracy blows up. Since there are $n^2$ states for a particular value of $n$ (obtained by summing the $2l+1$ states for a particular $n$ and $l$ with Gauss' formula), we can see that this does not out-compete the exponential decay with increasing energy, and the probability will still decrease with higher $n$.

@MattHanson Even if we restrict the system to negative energies with levels $n$, concentration of levels below energy 0 causes all probability to accumulate on the (infinity of) states just below energy 0.

I’m sorry, but that is incorrect. The energy gap at the lower energy levels is so large as to make anything but the lowest levels almost 0 occupation at anything other than ludicrous temperatures.

@MattHanson I don't think this is right. Increasing energy does indeed produce exponential decay, but energy does not increase without bound; it just increases toward the ionization energy of the electron, which is finite.

If you calculate the Boltzmann factors for the hydrogen atom energy levels (Rydberg formula) you find that at reasonable temperatures the entire population is concentrated in the ground state. Even at super high temperatures you only get modest contributions from the next energy levels. My point is that you’d have to be as hot as the sun before the higher energy levels even become relevant, which makes this whole degeneracy discussion seem quite silly.


Obviously, my reasoning is faulty, as it predicts all atoms to be ionized at all times, but that's not what we observe. I've been told that this is all due to interference from other (nearby) atoms, bringing about a 'cut-off' principal quantum number, beyond which the provided reasoning fails due to this interference being too strong. This explanation is dissatisfactory to me. Would we expect full ionisation, then, at low atom number densities, because the distance between atoms is larger?

Yes. Hypothetically, in interstellar space with low enough density of atoms/molecules with some persistent radiation, the few atoms that are there, are supposed to eventually ionize, because there are too many available states for the system acted upon radiation not doing that. With weak enough radiation, this may take some long time after the atom is introduced there, so not all atoms are expected to be ionized immediately.
The "problem" of how to apply quantum statistical physics to usual atoms and molecules that are not ionized has been "solved" by, I think, Fermi, by putting the atom/molecule in a box. The box isn't really there, but it is a formal device to modify the level structure to one that, together with Boltzmannian statistics, leads to acceptable level populations (usually, most probability in the ground state). Of course, the box and modification of the levels is a kludge, the "correct" way would be to analyze what happens to electronic states in an atom which interacts with many other nearby atoms. It is hard to do such analysis (too many particles and hard math). We know interaction usually splits pre-existing levels (destroys degeneracy), so the state density will become less concentrated around energy levels and more like a dense comb; but also, if there is enough atoms around, they should act on the one atom similarly to walls of a box, so some level repulsion should appear as well, which destroys the accumulation of states  one isolated atom has around energy level 0 and above.

What a fantastic answer, thank you :)

@ChangedMyName you're welcome.

Well, you shouldn't be using Boltzmann statistics on electrons in an atomic orbital in the first place- they are not distinguishable and follow Fermi-Dirac statistics. Of course, the Fermi Dirac statistics results approach that of Boltzmann at high enough temperature. Guess what else happens at high enough temperature: ionization.

I love you, Mike

You arent seeing the problem that the OP is pointing out. Even at low temperatures, and the Fermi-Dirac stats also asymptotically tending to zero just like exponential decay accounting for the near-ionisation states, the degeneracy ought to explode. The cut-off answer is far better; it at least answers the question.

Thank you, naturallyInconsistent. I will break up with Mike.

Those states do not exist. As the principal quantum number $n\to\infty$, the size of the atomic orbital also increases without bound. This is the result we obtained by imagining that there are no other thing in the universe, only the atom and nothing else. But if we want to apply the mathematical apparatus of statistical thermodynamics onto this system, we must have many copies of the same atomic system.
Thus, it is merely an approximation when we are saying that we can treat these atomic systems individually, applying those mathematical tricks. It is a tolerable approximation when these atoms are sparse apart and the interactions are weak and the temperatures are low. It is not at all tolerable an approximation when the atomic orbitals threatens to occupy the entire universe; then the electron orbitals necessarily overlap with each other than the interactions cannot be considered as weak any more. This means that the states near the $n\approx\infty$ limit are destroyed by the interaction and if you want to cover them properly, you must redo the calculation with better approximations of what the appropriate approximate states are.
